# Migrate VM Proxmox to Vmware

Tags: vmware-esxi, kvm-virtualization, vmware-vsphere, proxmox

I have a VM on proxmox with a vmdk harddrive on a IDE controller (it's a Windows Server 2019 VM)
I want to import the HD into a VM on Vsphere (ESXi 7).

I just copy the vmdk into the VM folder of the VM on ESX, clone the hardrive with the command:

```
vmkfstools -i disk.vmdk disk-thin.vmdk -d thin
```

And add the disk to the VM.

But the VM won't boot...

I tried to change the controller SCSI by IDE, but same, the VM won't boot...

Is there a step i forgot ?

Most of cases are qcow2 to vmdk so there is a qemu-convert command first on the proxmox server, but I am already in vmdk format.

Thx in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i found the issue, I have to put the microprogram to standard Bios and not UEFI